# Android studio - how to put multiple recyclerviews in activity and make the screen scrollable?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, scroll

I want to add multiple recycler views to the activity and I don't have enough space on the screen. How can I make the screen scrollable so I will have more space to add the recycler views?

Comment: Put all of them in a single `NestedScrollView` using a child `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your Solution is here

```
  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="300dp"/>

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="300dp"/>


      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="300dp"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Note:: Change the height of recycler view according to your need.
**Feel free to ask if
something is unclear**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have a big space between the two items I put there. How can I decrease it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two RecyclerViews on after another I would strongly recommend using only one with different ViewHolders depending on what you want to display.

```
enum class ContentType(val adapterTypeId: Int) {
    TYPE_ONE(AdapterTypeId.ADAPTER_TYPE_ONE),
    TYPE_TWO(AdapterTypeId.ADAPTER_TYPE_TWO);

    companion object {
        fun getTypeFromAdapterTypeId(adapterId: Int) = when (adapterId) {
            AdapterTypeId.ADAPTER_TYPE_ONE -> TYPE_ONE
            AdapterTypeId.ADAPTER_TYPE_TWO -> TYPE_TWO
            else -> throw RuntimeException("Unknown Content type")
        }
    }

    private object AdapterTypeId {
        const val ADAPTER_TYPE_ONE = 0
        const val ADAPTER_TYPE_TWO = 1
    }
}
```

Create a sealed class which will be the base class all your items will extend from:

```
sealed class GalleryContent(val contentType: ContentType)
```

Then in your Adapter:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (ContentType.getTypeFromAdapterTypeId(viewType)) {
        ContentType.TYPE_ONE -> // Bind proper ViewHolder
        ContentType.TYPE_TWO -> // Bind proper ViewHolder
    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val item = itemList[position]
    return item.contentType.adapterTypeId
}
```

Of course you can add as much as you want different types